# Overlaying line graph to a points chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to overlay the mean of the `abiotic` line over the point chart. I tried using geom_line as some other answers recommend but it doesn't quite work. I also want the mean of each point to be shown for each level.

```
sp <- rep(c("A","B"), times = 10)
sp.val <- rnorm(20,5,1)
abitoic <- rnorm(20,40,2)
level <- rep(c("Low","High"), each = 10)

df <- data.frame(sp, sp.val, abitoic, level)

pd = position_dodge(0.5)
ggplot(df, aes(x = level, y = sp.val, col = sp, group = sp)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = sp),colour="white",pch=21, size=4, stroke = 1, alpha = 0.7, position = pd) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar",
               width = 0.5, colour = "black",
               position = pd) + 
  stat_summary(fun = median, color = "black", 
               geom = "point", size = 7,show.legend = FALSE,
               position = pd) +
  stat_summary(fun = median, 
               geom = "line", show.legend = FALSE,
               position = pd)+
  stat_summary(fun = median,
               geom = "point", size = 3,show.legend = FALSE,
               position = pd) +
  geom_line(aes(x = level, y = abitoic/5, group = level))
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but I think you might be looking for this: `stat_summary(aes(x = level, y = abitoic/5, group = 1), fun = mean, geom = 'line', inherit.aes = FALSE)`. Not sure what _"I also want the mean of each point to be shown for each level"_ means though.

Comment: @Axeman That worked. If you can write that into an answer I can upvote it